# chrome extension launchWebAuthFlow error

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, opera-extension

`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`
method always throw error **Authorization page could not be loaded.**

When requesting with:

`"&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080"`
the Google's auth popup appears but after you sign in: error appears.

`"&redirect_uri=" + chrome.identity.getRedirectURL()` error throws immediately

I need to login Google from Opera extension so `getAuthToken` will not work for me.

Comment: Try following this [reported issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=559523) and this [Chrome App: identity.launchWebAuthFlow: Authorization page could not be loaded](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/issues/200), as stated by **rlmcneary2**: "You must have the appID match the OAuth callback URLs."

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Hey thanks for the answer but i gave up. I have configured everything following Google's guides such as manifest 'oauth2' and 'key' fields so my ID is persist every time i reload\update extension. Also i have already checked some of links presented by you.

Comment: Also **getAuthToken** in chrome works just fine. Which means client_id and appID is fine too. Also i haven't try other services that uses oauth2 maybe the problem is actual only for accounts.google.com

Answer (score 1):

I have found soluntion. You should create "Web app" with `redirect uri=https://<appid>.chromiumapp.org/` when creating oauth2 client in google dev console instead of "chrome app".